# canvas draw text width

Tags: html, html5-canvas

```
ctx.font="73px 方正兰亭特黑简体";
var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,403,0);
gradient.addColorStop("0","#ffa91a");
gradient.addColorStop("0.5","#ffe846");
gradient.addColorStop("1.0","#ffef8c");
ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
;
ctx.fillText("fwefwefewf",495,230);
```

The problem how to capture text, because the width of the text is a dynamic of the 403 I want to change the width of the text

Comment: I'm really sorry to say this, and I want to be polite... but this is the most incomprehensible question on SO I saw so far!  I was trying to leave some constructive feedback but I couldn't understand your problem after reading your "question" 3 times.

Comment: I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer by editing your question in order to actually be in the form of a question: what is it that you would like to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `measureText()` method of context:

```
ctx.font="73px 方正兰亭特黑简体";

var txt = 'fwefwefewf';
var txtWidth = ctx.measureText(txt).width;   /// width in pixels

var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0, txtWidth, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0,  "#ffa91a");
gradient.addColorStop(0.5,"#ffe846");
gradient.addColorStop(1.0,"#ffef8c");
ctx.fillStyle=gradient;

ctx.fillText(txt, 495,230);
```

Just remember to take the text *position* into consideration as well for the gradient.